# Best practices for packaging libraries that use cython using poetry

Tags: python, cython, pypi, cicd, python-poetry

I've always used `poetry` to develop python packages. Now I want to use Cython in a new project and I'm a little confuse about how to structure de library, whether or not to use a `setup.py` instead of using `poetry` at all.

I've seen posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505747/how-should-i-structure-a-python-package-that-contains-cython-code)) about how to include `cython` code in a package (with a `setup.py`) but not using poetry. Others, [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63679316/11915595) (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66653228/package-installed-failed-with-poetry-backend)) does, but they depend on a `build.py` script, and a comment said in one of them that approach wont work if `gcc` is not installed.

So, what would be the best practices for packaging (and publishing to PyPI) libraries that use cython using poetry?

Comment: I know this is an older post, but it's the first result when constraining my search to last year. At least for the lack of `gcc`, I can tell you that `cython` simply won't work without a C compiler, period. What Cython does is generate C code, which needs to be compiled. It's not a compiler itself. And `gcc` is the default compier on Linux.